# Crazy Finished Message in TLS

Tags: ssl

I'm tried to uderstand what is the content of the `Finished Message` of TLS. I'm using wireshark to capture the traffic between my browser and the internet. I noticed a "stangeness" when the chosen ciphersuite is AES_GCM. Beign it a stream-cipher, it hash no padding. If I got it right, the data being sent in the Finished Message is:

- 8 bytes Explicit Nonce
- 12 bytes verify_data
- 16 bytes authentication tag

That is, **36 bytes** in total. The "problem" is that the Finished Message packet size is **40 bytes**.

And here it is:

[image]

Why the message packet is 40 bytes and what are the red bytes?

And why wireshark sees two hello requests?

And another this... the Client answers with a **176 bytes** packet:

[image]

I'm getting crazy...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: originally I thought the message was corrupted, but dave_thompson's comment is correct and the Finished message is encrypted with GCM (I originally assumed CBC), so answer is fixed in light of this new information.

Looking at the server's binary content, 14 03 03 00 01 01 is the Change Cipher Spec Message, which is followed by the following bytes (and my explanation of what they mean):

16 (Handshake record header)
03 03 (TLS Version 1.2)
00 28 (length of message)
00 00 ...[40 bytes] (encrypted message)

Dave's comment below correctly describes the encrypted AES GCM structure.  However, based on Wireshark's analysis, it appears that Wireshark does not understand that an encrypted message is next (after Change Cipher Spec), so it tries to parse it as an unencrypted handshake message.  The leading 0x00 indicates a message type of Hello Request, and the later data do not contradict this, so Wireshark incorrectly parses this as an unencrypted Hello Request instead of the encrypted Finished message.

Regarding 36 bytes vs 40 bytes, the finished message is 16 bytes:
1 byte header (0x14 for Finished)
3 bytes length(0x00000c for 12 bytes)
12 bytes data

These extra 4 bytes (header and length of Finished message) account for the difference.

For the 176 byte client message that comes next, 176 bytes is the encrypted record length.  Without decrypting I can't say what's in it, but it starts with 0x16, which indicates a handshake, so it's probably a Client Finished message along with one or more other handshake messages.

Comment: **For GCM** the encrypted record has 8 bytes explicit nonce which can be and here is a copy of the sequence number which for Finished is zero, the CTR-encrypted data, and 16 bytes tag (regardless of the hash named in the ciphersuite); see crossdupes http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57804/strange-finished-message-in-tls  and http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57807/crazy-finished-message-in-tls

Answer (score 1):

#Why 40 bytes?

> Why the message packet is 40 bytes and what are the red bytes?

I don't know. Anything after a "Change Cipher Spec" is encrypted.
From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.1 :

```
The ChangeCipherSpec message is sent [...]
before the verifying Finished message is sent.
[...] once the ChangeCipherSpec has been sent, the
new CipherSpec MUST be used.
```

From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.9 :

```
The Finished message is the first one protected with
the just negotiated algorithms, keys, and secrets.
```

#Why two?

> And why wireshark sees two hello requests?

I guess it got confused trying to interpret encrypted data.

**Suggestion**

- Try capturing again but this time have Firefox log the premaster secret. Then use the premaster secret to decrypt with WireShark. See: [SecSE question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35639/decrypting-tls-in-wireshark-when-using-dhe-rsa-ciphersuites/42350#42350)